# Is there a proper term to use when you're referring to the total number of people on an aircraft, including both the passengers and crew/pilots?

Tags: terminology

I've found that often when people quote the number of passengers on an aircraft, they exclude the crew/pilots, which they'll provide separately.

Is there a proper term to use when you're referring to or asking for the total number of people on the aircraft, including both the passengers and crew/pilots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CAP 419](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?catid=1&appid=11&mode=detail&id=6973) (the UK CAA radio telephony manual, see the glossary) uses 'POB' which stands for '(total) persons on board'

Answer (score 2):

I would answer xyz POB if asked the question. It's a standard enquiry at some airports after landing, together with aircraft registration

Answer (score 1):

The term "complement" is sometimes used for the total capacity of the craft, as in "it has a full complement of passengers and crew on board."

Answer (score 0):

Souls on board. Living people on board, cadavers do not count.

Comment: Please add a reference to back up this answer.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_3.html
which deals with emergency reporting:

Table 5-3-11

DM57 (remaining fuel) OF FUEL REMAINING AND (remaining souls) SOULS ON BOARD
Note - N response attribute

Report indicating fuel remaining (time) and number of persons on board.

(remaining fuel) ENDURANCE AND (persons on board) PERSONS ON BOARD

While for VFR and IFR flight plans 'persons' is used:

91.153   VFR flight plan: Information required.
(a) Information required. Unless otherwise authorized by ATC, each person filing a VFR flight plan shall include in it the following information:
     (8) The number of persons in the aircraft, except where that information is otherwise readily available to the FAA.

91.169   IFR flight plan: Information required.
(1) Information required under §91.153 (a) of this part;